# Automatically start a program in a new CMD instance

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a batch script that will open a new instance of CMD under different credentials, and automatically launch a program from that instance.

My "runas" command is:

> runas /user:USER@DOMAIN cmd

After typing in a password, a new cmd instance opens, but I can't get it to automatically run the program I want.
How do I do this?
Also, if it's possible to close the new cmd instance after it launches the program, that will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
runas /user:user:domain "cmd /c \"echo testing ^& pause ^& exit\""
```

- quote the full command
- inner quotes must be escaped as `\"`
- inner problematic characters must be escaped as `^&`, `^>`, ...

Answer (score 0):

basically you want to pass an argument to the program you specify with runas

This [article here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/04/28/how-can-i-use-the-runas-command-to-run-a-script-under-alternate-user-credentials.aspx) suggests a way to do it

> runas /profile /user:fabrikam\kenmyer "cscript.exe C:\Scripts\Test.vbs"

Answer (score 0):

A user answered my question and then deleted his answer.
It worked for me, and I was too late to tick his answer, so I'm posting his answer here.

> runas /user:USER@DOMAIN "cmd /c start program.exe"

This also closes the new CMD instance after launching "program.exe"
Thank you, kind stranger!